# Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main JavaFx IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Main
```

these are my 2 errors and I have no way out of it, I am using JavaFX SDK 16, and JDK version 16.0.1
Is there a way to fix it other than redownloading and installing them again?

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=,suspend=y,server=n --module-path C:/JavaFx/openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-16/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -javaagent:C:\Users\ohmar\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\src.zip;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\JavaFx\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" sample.Main
Connected to the target VM, address: '', transport: 'socket'
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Main
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This is all I all got in my stack trace

Comment: Does this help? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

Comment: OMG, thank you I was trying to debug this for 3 hours last night, Thank you, WORKS like magic! I don't have enough reputation to upvote you, I would have if I did.
Thanks again